# django 1.7 User Registration form with profile picture

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to create a user registration form in Django which extends the default user model to include a user profile picture/avatar?  Ive seen quite a few answers on here but I get lost on how to implement these when it comes to submitting the form?

I use Twitter Bootstrap to create the form in HTML since I do not like the default Django CSS offers.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your work so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible,
check the below link for registering user with profile picture

[Register user](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/login.html#creating-a-user-registration-view-and-template)

and for integrating with bootstrap on the same site you can find this

[integrate with bootstrap](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/bootstrap.html)

Comment: thanks, ill need to read up on it. thanks for the links. They seem to point in the right direction.